# Install solutions like ClickOnce

Tags: deployment, windows-installer, clickonce

Are there other things out there like ClickOnce, but that use the actual application files?

I am finding the signing and packaging process very difficult to pass off to others.

I have tools than can make an MSI.  But the deploy process of ClickOnce is very useful.

**Is there something out there that works like ClickOnce but uses an MSI?**

NOTE: I need what ever I use to not require the help of my System Admins.  They are in a different structure of my company and rolling out my releases via them would delay things too much.  (This means that using a Group Policy is not feasible.

Comment: "like ClickOnce" ... details please. What exactly dou you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Installshield has in their Premier and Professional editions has a feature that will check for updates before each execution, just like a ClickOnce application, which sounds like just what you are asking for.  However, the price is not cheap.

http://www.flexerasoftware.com/products/software-installation/installshield-software-installer/tab/features